# JavaScript localeCompare() returns different result than Java compareTo()

Tags: javascript, java, string, string-comparison

What I am trying to achieve is to synchronize the outcome of these two functions. 
These methods return number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.

The JavaScript localeCompare has many parameters to be set but nothing from what I have tried worked.

```
**Java returns**:      **JavaScript returns**:
Sensor             Sensor
SensorDus          Sensor DUS
SensorEnv          Sensor E
Sensor DUS         SensorDUS
Sensor E           Sensor Env
```

It looks like that the difference it those two methods is how they return the numbers. 
A negative number if the reference string occurs before the compare string; positive if the reference string occurs after the compare string; 0 if they are equivalent.

Any ideas if this is somehow possible?

Comment: none of these results are possible. localeCompareTo and compareTo return a single numerical value. You'll need to check your actual comparison code. Basically, this is the same question you've asked earlier (and deleted). And you make the same errors in your question. Look at the relevant sorting  code, not at the compareTo. or, show the compareTo implementations

Answer (score 3):

My solution to the problem. 
Instead of using localeCompare() I rewrote the Java compareTo() into JavaScript method. The java method returned positive (higher) number for white space as opposed to string without a white space in JavaScript.

```
localCompareAsInJava: function(t1,t2)
{
  var len1 = t1.length;
  var len2 = t2.length;
  var lim = Math.min(t1.length, t2.length);

  var v1 = t1;
  var v2 = t2;

  var k = 0;
  while(k < lim)
  {
    var c1 = v1[k];
    var c2 = v2[k];
    if(c1 != c2)
    {
      if(c1.charCodeAt(0) == 32 )
      {
        var charWithSpace = c1.charCodeAt(0) + c2.charCodeAt(0); 
        return charWithSpace;
      }
      else{
        return c1.charCodeAt(0) - c2.charCodeAt(0);
      }

    }
    k++;
  }
  return len1 - len2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i needed.